# Django page not found although everything seems okay

Tags: python, django, routes

I am new to Django and I am doing everything that is indicated in Django documentation but I can not figure out why it keeps saying Page Not Found

I tried changing the path or Debug=True to Debug=False but nothing interesting happened. It once worked but now it keeps saying Page Not Found.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("mainpage/", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

this is urls.py mainpage

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("My first page")
```

this is views.py mainpage

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [

    path("mainpage/", include("mainpage.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

```and this one is urls.py mysite 

this is the result:
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

mainpage/ mainpage/ [name='mainpage']
admin/
The current path, mainpage/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainpage/
````

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainpage/mainpage/` would work. In your `urls.py` you include `mainpage.urls` if the path starts with `mainpage/`. In `mainpage.urls` you check for `mainpage/` again. Together this is `mainpage/mainpage/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you have set it up the correct url would be mainpage/mainpage.

By having this code path("mainpage/", include("mainpage.urls")) in your project's urls all of your paths found in mainpage.urls will have mainpage/ on the beginning. By including mainpage/ again in the app urls you end up with mainpage/mainpage.

I hope this is the issue and helps.